# Evaluate the Line Integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the line integral[image]where [image] and C is given by the vector function [image],[image]

That should be a simple question but I'm getting a wrong answer!
The way I did it is evaluating the integral with t instate of x,y,z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your curve $C$ $x = t^6$, $y = -t^5$, and $y = t^4$.  Now find $d\vec{r}$ and dot it with your function (by plugging in those values for $x$, $y$, and $z$):

$$
d\vec{r} = \vec{r}'(t)dt = \langle 6t^5, -5t^4, 4t^3\rangle dt \\
\vec{F}\circ d\vec{r} = -5\sin\left(t^6\right)6t^5 + 5\cos\left(-t^5\right)5t^4 + 5t^6t^44t^3 \\
\vec{F}\circ d\vec{r} = -30t^5\sin\left(t^6\right) + 25t^4\cos\left(t^5\right) + 20t^{13}
$$

This integral is pretty easy to take:

\begin{align}
\int\limits_0^1 \vec{F}\circ d\vec{r} =& \left.5\cos\left(t^6\right) + 5\sin\left(t^5\right) + \frac{20}{14}t^{14}\right|_0^1 \\
=& 5\cos(1) - 5 + 5\sin(1) + \frac{10}{7}
\end{align}